# How to find a type of certain object in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, inheritance

I have 4 classes. 
1) `Employee` class
2) `Nurse` class that `extends Employee`
3) `Doctor` class that also `extends Employee`
4) `Supervisor` class that `extends Doctor`

Inside Supervisor I have a property: `private Employee[] arrayOfEmployees;`

Basically an array of Employees that inside are doctors and nurses.
now i want to build a function inside the Supervisor class that will return the number of nurses within the array.

My problem is that I don't know how to access the array because the array type is Employee and I look for Nurse.

Can someone help me with this function?

Comment: You're looking for `instanceof` operator.

Comment: You can invoke `getClass` on an `Employee` object, which will resolve its instance class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use java 8 you can use streams for this:

```
int numNurses = Arrays
    .stream(employeeArray)
    .filter(e -> e instanceof Nurse.class)
    .count();
```

Comment: This is a fine solution, however it requires an object creation that appears unnecessary.  Why not use the `count()` terminal operation?

Answer (score 0):

Just with the **instanceof** keyword.

```
if (arrayOfEmployees[i] instanceof Nurse) {
    Nurse nurse = (Nurse) arrayOfEmployees[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using java 8 and streams

```
//array of employees 3 Nurses & 2 Docs
E[] aOfE = new E[] { new N(), new N(), new N(), new D(), new D() };

Predicate<E> pred = someEmp -> N.class.isInstance(someEmp);
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(aOfE).filter(pred).count());
```

where the class:

```
E=Employee, N=Nurse, D=Doctor
```

or using lambdas

```
E[] aOfE = new E[] { new N(), new N(), new N(), new D(), new D() };


System.out.println(Arrays.stream(aOfE).filter(someEmp -> N.class.isInstance(someEmp)).count());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Supervisor supervisor = new Supervisor();
        supervisor.arrayOfEmployees = new Employee[] {new Nurse(), new Doctor(), new Doctor(), new Nurse()};

        //will be 2
        long numberOfNurses = supervisor.numberOfNurses();

        System.out.println(numberOfNurses);
    }
}

class Employee {}

class Doctor extends Employee {}

class Nurse extends Employee {}

class Supervisor extends Doctor {
    Employee[] arrayOfEmployees;

    long numberOfNurses() {
        return Stream.of(arrayOfEmployees).filter(e -> e instanceof Nurse).count();
    }
}
```